# Explanation of $ in Mule MEL

Tags: mule, mel

I cannot find any documentation around the use of $ in MEL other than a couple of lines [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference)

> You can refer to any Java class by its fully qualified name or if it
>   is one of the classes in the automatically-imported Java classes, by
>   its unqualified name. References use the same dot notation as in Java,
>   except that you must use $ rather than a dot to refer to a nested
>   class.

I can find a couple of examples [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/download/attachments/122752116/refcard-mel.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1404857929206)

> JSON processing MEL has no direct support for JSON. The
>   json-to-object-transformer can turn a JSON payload into a hierarchy of
>   simple data structures that are easily parsed with MEL. For example,
>   the following uses a filtered projection to build the equivalent of
>   the

```
$..[?
(@.title=='Moby Dick')].price JSON path expression:
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" />
<expression-transformer
 expression="#[($.price in message.payload if $.title == 'Moby Dick')[0]]" />
```

I want to understand in which cases does the $ get used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` comes from MVEL, the language underlying MEL.

> $ serves as the placeholder for the element being filtered. It is
>   actually a regular variable that exists inside the context of the
>   projection. You can also use it to return the current element in the
>   projection to the representative list.

Reference: http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Projections+and+Folds#MVEL2.0ProjectionsandFolds-Filters